# How does pandas qcut decide the bin edges

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe, and I want to bin the continuous values.

```
a['abc'].describe() # a name of pandas dataframe, abc--column name
count    250000.000000
mean         43.412040
std          26.075295
min           0.000000
25%          25.000000
50%          38.000000
75%          53.000000
max         218.000000
Name: abc, dtype: float64
```

On using pandas `qcut` for 4 groups, how is a negative value assigned in one of bins?

```
a["abc_bin"] = pd.qcut(a["abc"],4,labels=None,)
print(a["abc_bin"].value_counts())

(25.0, 38.0]      73448
(-0.001, 25.0]    62818
(53.0, 218.0]     61605
(38.0, 53.0]      52129
Name: abc_bin, dtype: int64
```

How is the bin width is decided? In particular, how is there a negative value as a bin edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why does one bin include negative values?

This is because the resulting intervals are open on the left, so pandas extends the left edge to include the min. Based on your `describe` output, the min is 0, so the left edge becomes slightly negative:

- `(0, 25.0]` does **not** include 0
- `(-0.001, 25.0]` includes 0

This is not documented in [**`qcut`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html), but similar behavior is explained in [**`cut`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

> **`bins`**: ... The range of `x` is extended by 0.1% on each side to include the minimum and maximum values of `x`.

---

#### How are the bins determined?

[**`qcut`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) adjusts the edges such that each bin contains the same number of elements, whereas [**`cut`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) just divides strictly at the edges.

- So with [**`cut`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), we can avoid the negative edge by [specifying a list of bins](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20423#issuecomment-374721405) because the data gets split exactly at those edges:

  ```py
  a = pd.DataFrame({'abc': np.random.random(size=10000)})
  pd.cut(a['abc'], [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]).value_counts()

  # (0.25, 0.5]    2637
  # (0.0, 0.25]    2478
  # (0.75, 1.0]    2454
  # (0.5, 0.75]    2431
  # Name: abc, dtype: int64
  ```
- But with [**`qcut`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html), this workaround has no effect since [**`qcut`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) always adjusts the edges to force the bins into equal counts:

  ```
  pd.qcut(a['abc'], [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]).value_counts()

  # (-0.000818, 0.253]    2500
  # (0.253, 0.489]        2500
  # (0.489, 0.745]        2500
  # (0.745, 1.0]          2500
  # Name: abc, dtype: int64
  ```